# How to read all object properties from Ontology in Java using Jena library?

Tags: java, rdf, owl, apache-jena

I want to read all the Object Properties present in the OWL file. I have created that OWL file using Protege tool. I have loaded the model also but I am not able to fetch the object properties.

> For Example: if I have a class in Ontology named as Car and which has
>   several Object and Data properties linked to it, such as hasColor,
>   hasAudioSystem,hasGps.

I want to get all the object properties linked with that particular class through Domain and Range or only through the name of the class. Please help..

Comment: Can you clarify how the object properties are "linked" to the class? Are they stated as domain/range? Class restrictions? Instance data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the list of object properties having a type declared as domain or range, one way of doing it with Jena is the following:

```
public void objectPropertiesForType(Model m, final Resource type) {
    StmtIterator i = m.listStatements(new SimpleSelector() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Statement s) {
            if (s.getPredicate().equals(RDFS.domain)
                    || s.getPredicate().equals(RDFS.range)) {
                return (s.getObject().equals(type));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Statement s = i.next();
        System.out.println("Property: " + s.getSubject().getURI());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jena, you'd probably want to retrieve an instance of OntClass for the class, and then use the [listDeclaredProperties](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#listDeclaredProperties%28boolean%29) method, which will:

> Return an iterator over the properties associated with a frame-like
>   view of this class. This captures an intuitive notion of the
>   properties of a class. This can be useful in presenting an ontology
>   class in a user interface, for example by automatically constructing a
>   form to instantiate instances of the class. The properties in the
>   frame-like view of the class are determined by comparing the domain of
>   properties in this class's OntModel with the class itself.